# function(x) check x and for every +1 to x, add 5 to y?

Tags: javascript

I know this is rookie stuff but I can't even figure out to how to look up this problem.

I want this:

```
function(x){
y = x / 8;
z = Math.ceil(y);
time = "";
when y = 1, add 5 to time
 so:
when y = 3, time = 15..
when y = 5, time - 25, etc.
}
```

Like I said, this Javascript 101 I'm sure but I'm currently having trouble pull out of my head. I feel like this is a pretty crucial thing to know how to do.

EDIT:

I'm trying to build a better version of this below function. I should have initially posted this, sorry!

```
function cookingTime(x) {
  if (x == 0){
    return 0;
  }
  else {
    var time = x / 8;
    if (Math.ceil(time) == 1) {
      return 5;
    }
    if (Math.ceil(time) == 2) {
      return 10;
    }
    if (Math.ceil(time) == 3) {
      return 15;
    }
  }
}
```

The below function works for what I was asking about for reference:

```
function(x) { return Math.ceil(x/8) * 5 }
```

Comment: out of curiosity, is `z` necessary for anything you're not showing or should it be used for calculating time instead of `y`?

Comment: z is to take y and put it in a group kind of. So that the behavior is set to every grouping based on 8. Does that make sense?

Comment: Joy Rê figured me out, thanks guys!

Comment: Its is not Javascript 101. Its Algorithm 101!

Comment: It's all just Learnsometingbesidescssandhtml101 to me right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to return that variable time?  Instead you can write

```
function(x) { return Math.ceil(x/8) * 5 }
```

If I understand what you want the function to do, you don't need so many variables, and I don't think you even want to set time as a string ("") since you are working with numbers here.

Comment: I should have posted this initially, sorry.

Comment: I edited my post to explain better what I'm trying to do. This is my solution, thanks!! I was over thinking everything thinking I needed a for each loop or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script>
   time = 0;var a;
   function fun()
   {
      var x=parseInt(document.f1.t1.value);
      y = x / 8;
      z = Math.ceil(y);alert(z);
      a=5*z;
      time=time+a;
      alert(time);
   }
</script>
<body>
<form name="f1">
<input type="text" name="t1">
<input type="button" name="b1" onclick="fun()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```